# PowerShell - Creating a back up of a script then overwriting

Tags: powershell

I'd like to backup a script that I have, then append a new string to the file. Whenever I try to create a backup, I can no longer append to the file.

Here is the code:

```
             #Back the file
              if (-NOT (Test-Path -Path $someFile".bak"))
              {
                 Copy-Item -Path $someFile -Destination $someFile".bak"
              }
                
            if (-NOT ($json.CaptureSettings.IncludeProcess))
            {   
               Set-Content $someFile -Value $(
               @(
                 switch -Wildcard -File $someFile{
                 '#*' { $_ }
                 default { break }
                 }
                 # Append the dummy process string to the file
                ) + "`n`n# Dummy process inserted here", "`n EMPTY_PROCESS.EXE"
               )
            }
```

I am new to PowerShell and I am unfamiliar why it won't enter the Set-Content function. It will enter the if statement, but will not do anything with Set-Content.

**Edit:** I believe it's not finding anything with a '#*' despite it working before.

This function will work if I don't include the first 4 lines of code (the first if statement) that create the back up.

Comment: @Daniel What you specified is my intent. I am looking to parse the file, keep every line that starts with a '#' and then append the dummy process line.

Answer (score 0):

The question is a bit vague, but if I understand correctly, you would like to keep only the lines that start with `#` and append new lines to the file after that.

In that case you can do:

```
$newContent = switch -Wildcard -File $someFile {
    '#*' { $_ }   # keep all lines starting with #
}
$newContent | Set-Content -Path $someFile
# Append the dummy process string to the file
Add-Content -Path $someFile -Value "`r`n# Dummy process inserted here`r`nEMPTY_PROCESS.EXE"
```

Or you can also do this without using a switch:

```
$newContent = Get-Content -Path $someFile | Where-Object { $_ -like '#*' }
$newContent | Set-Content -Path $someFile
# Append the dummy process string to the file
Add-Content -Path $someFile -Value "`r`n# Dummy process inserted here`r`nEMPTY_PROCESS.EXE"
```

Oh yes, change the concatting of the .bak file like you do with `$someFile".bak"` into

```
'{0}.bak' -f $someFile
```

or

```
($someFile + '.bak')
```

or

```
"${someFile}.bak"
```